# Geolocation in HTML5 When browser not active

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation

I use geolocation API periodically to get the current location and store in my web app. But when used via mobile device (Android) the location upload stops when I lock the screen or open another app. This makes my location tracking part of my web app useless. Is it working only when the tab is active?

If so is there a way to get around this?

I use chrome is Android, wi-fi/high accuracy enabled.

Thanks
Ish